# Google App Maker / sql instance location & GDPR

Tags: google-app-maker

I’ve been looking into using App Maker within our company and during setup (we're based in the UK & and bound by GDPR), the App Maker utility wouldn’t work unless the SQL instance was set up with its location in the `us-central1` region.

Q. Is it possible to set the location to London? And if we must use the `us-central1` rection, is it possible at the point of publishing the designed app to create a database in Europe/London, or to migrate to a SQL instance there?

It would be preferable to retain the data within the UK, for GDPR compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql server can be in any region or even on prem.

From the docs found at :
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053

> Region: us-central1 (recommended) We recommend that you use the
>   us-central1 region for your new instance, regardless of your
>   geographic location. You can select a different region, but app
>   performance might not be satisfactory because apps are run in
>   us-central.